# Left Click Function For Javascript/Html Game

Tags: javascript, menu, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

A friend and I are coding a game similar to Subway surfers/temple run with that type of running, coin collecting concept through html and javascript. The game is 2 dimensional and instead of the objects coming towards like they would in 3d, they come from above. We have a majority of the work done; however we were unable to figure out how to do a function for a mouse left click so we just resorted with doing something like this

if (event.keyCode == 114 ) {

startGame()

--> and then your skin menu will pop up

We were wondering how we could make it so instead of clicking a key such as "s", to open the menu to change your skin, upon death a thing will pop up saying Change Skin, and you can left click on that and continue from there. Thank You.

Comment: we don't know  anything about how your game is made, how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: if it's a dom element, you have the mouse events for that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent